# How do I install hp officejet printer 4610/4620 onto my apple 4th generation IPad?

Tags: macos, ipad, printing

I have an HP Officejet 4610/4620 attached to an OSX machine, and I would like to print to it from my 4th generation iPad Apple - how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

This should be as simple as downloading and installing *Handyprint* (previously known as *AirPrint Activator*) which will share out an OSX printer on your wireless network as if it was an Airprint one.  Check it out [here](http://www.netputing.com/handyprint/).